# Asp.net wizard control's Next button behavior seems to be getting altered by another control?

Tags: asp.net, wizard

I have an asp.net wizard control in my application. I have no explanation for the behavior I'm seeing but here is what it's doing.

The wizard collects data from the user, and at the bottom of the first step in the wizard, I have a disclaimer stating the user agrees by the terms and conditions with a checkbox that indicates their agreement. Rather than put all of the terms in the wizard, I have another aspx page that has all of that spelled out. In the wizard, I have a statement that reads "I *-your name here-* agree to the **Terms and Conditions**." Terms and conditions is an asp LinkButton that performs a crosspage postback to my other page with my terms spelled out, and it opens in a new window/tab.

Where things get crazy is when you go to click the "Continue" button to advance to the second step of the wizard. If the user does NOT click on the LinkButton to view the terms, everything works great - the data form is validated and the wizard proceeds to the next step. However, if they click on the Terms and Conditions link button, it will post back to my terms page and display the terms with their entered name on that page - as it should. This is the part I can't explain... when they come back to the wizard and click the Continue button, it opens yet another Terms and Conditions tab and DOES NOT advance to the next wizard step.

It's like clicking the LinkButton control somehow rewires what the wizard's Next button should do. But it only happens if the LinkButton is clicked.

Here is my wizard declaration...

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" CellSpacing="5" Font-Names="Verdana" DisplaySideBar="False"
            ActiveStepIndex="0" FinishCompleteButtonText="Submit" StartNextButtonText="Continue" Width="100%" OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick" OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
            <StartNavigationTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#091C49" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CommandName="MoveNext" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="Continue" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
            </StartNavigationTemplate>
            <StepNavigationTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#091C49" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="Previous" />
                <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#091C49" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CommandName="MoveNext" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="Next" />
            </StepNavigationTemplate>
            <StepStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <SideBarStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Height="100%" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                VerticalAlign="Top" Width="140px" />
            <NavigationButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#091c49" BorderStyle="Solid"
                BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" />
```

Here is the checkbox and link button at the bottom of the first wizard step.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbSignature" runat="server" Checked="false" OnClick="ShowHideCVText()" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvCheckBoxRequired" EnableClientScript="true" Font-Bold="true" OnServerValidate="CheckBoxRequired_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBox" ErrorMessage="You must indicate that you have read and agree to the terms and conditions of this lease by checking the chekcbox below to continue." ForeColor="Red">*</asp:CustomValidator> 
                                I <asp:Label ID="lblSignatureName" runat="server" /> have read and fully understand the <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLeaseTerms2" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';" CausesValidation="false" PostBackUrl="~/LeaseAgreement" Text="Terms &amp; Conditions" />  of the lease agreement between blah blah blah...
```

Could it be something to do with the hack I'm using to make the LinkButton open into a new window? Seems unlikely as it's on a separate control but I don't know.

```
OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';"
```

This is the only thing that happens in code behind when going from step 1 to 2... just populating some label controls with entered text values.

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    lblCustomersName.Text = txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text;
    lblCustomersPhone.Text = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
    lblPhoneType.Text = rblPhoneType.SelectedItem.Text;
    lblCustomerStreetAddress.Text = txtStreetAddress.Text + Environment.NewLine +
                                    txtCity.Text + ", " + ddlState.SelectedItem.Text + " " + txtZip.Text;
    lblCustomersEmail.Text = txtEmailAddress.Text;
    lblParkingLength.Text = ddlLengthNeeded.SelectedItem.Text;
    lblVehicleYear.Text = txtVehicleYear.Text;
    lblRegisteredOwner.Text = txtRegisteredOwner.Text;
    lblVehicleMake.Text = txtVehicleMake.Text;
    //lblVehicleLicensePlate.Text = txtLicensePlate.Text;
    lblLeaseDuration.Text = ddlLeaseDuration.SelectedItem.Text;
    lblSummarySignature.Text = txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text;
}
```

Thoroughly confused at this point as to why the link button being clicked is changing the behavior of the Wizard's Continue button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading Jack Arbiter's comments above, that helped me figure out the target issue. Basically I call the function below from the link button's OnClientClick event, it sets the target to a new window and then waits a second and resets it back to itself.

```
function handlePostBack() {
        window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank';

        setTimeout(function () {
            window.document.forms[0].target = '_self';
        }, 1000);
    }
```

To figure out the postback issue, I actually stumbled onto that by looking in the Designer view of the Wizard. If you go to Design view and expand the Wizard control with the ">" button you will notice there is an "Edit Templates" option there. I selected that and then had to expand that Designer thing with the ">" button again. Once I did that, I was able to select the "Start Navigation Template" as that is where my "Continue" button is. When you click on the Continue button, you get all the properties of the button exposed in the properties window including PostBackUrl. I noticed it was not set, as I believe it defaults to PostBack to itself. I explicitly set it there to postback to itself and wa-lah... problem solved.

Here is the effect it had on the markup:

```
<StartNavigationTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#091C49" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CommandName="MoveNext" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="Continue" UseSubmitBehavior="False" PostBackUrl="~/LeaseOnline.aspx" />
            </StartNavigationTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any asp button within a form will submit the form unless you use OnClientClick="return false;" which is not desirable in this situation since you're using onclick and that will disable onclick.

Since the button submits the form, it submits to that form's target, which you have changed (you figured this out yourself, pretty much).

If I were you I would just use a standard HTML link instead of linkbutton:

```
<a href="~/LeaseAgreement" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
```

Or if you really need that to be a linkbutton you could reset the form target to `''` with a javascript setTimeout function, but I'm not sure if `''` will work without testing first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I do need to use a linkbutton (or button I suppose) as the link to the Terms Page is a Post, not a Get. I need information (user's entered name) from the form displayed in the terms page. I really did not want to use querystrings either. I've not worked with session variables before but it seems that is about the only other option unless someone knows how to Post to a different page. A simple html anchor tag will not do that per my understanding.

Comment: In that case, see my last sentence; keep OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';" but add a settimeout after the semicolon to change the form target back to ''

Comment: I see your point now. I believe this will resolve the targeting issue, but it will not set the page to postback to the source page. It will likely still postback to the terms page. That is only desired if clicking the link button. If the wizard button is clicked, it needs to postback to itself. I'm getting a better understanding of what's happening though. Thanks!